# Change default value on field after migration in django

Tags: python, django, database, migration

I have app in django 1.11 and I made migration. Now I have items in admin panel with 'John' in `first_name` and 'Smith' in `last_name` field. I would like to change it. Can I do this after made `python manage.py migrate`?

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='downloadlink',
        name='company',
        field=models.CharField(default='Company', max_length=500),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='downloadlink',
        name='first_name',
        field=models.CharField(default='John', max_length=500),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='downloadlink',
        name='last_name',
        field=models.CharField(default='Smith', max_length=500),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these steps,

**Step1**. Revert all migartions of app by **`python manage.py migrate app_name zero`**
**Step2**. Edit the migration file and save
**Step3**. Migrate the database again by, **`python manage.py migrate app_name`**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make the changes in the admin console, which is usually accessed at localhost:8000/admin. 
You will have to click on the Model in the admin console and make the changes for the instance.